# Select parent with children that has a certain class

Tags: jquery

*Updated question with real-life code:*
I have this

```
jQuery("dt").has("a.is-expanded").addClass("is-expanded");
```

and

```
<dt><a href="#accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger is-collapsed is-expanded" aria-expanded="true">Our services</a></dt>
```

I expected this to add the class of is-expanded to the dt since it contains an a with the class of is-expanded. But that does not happen andf I don't understand why? If I just put a then it works, but not if I put a.is-expanded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make use of hasClass()

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI's accordion? When is the code being executed?

Comment: @Amit's Interesting question is interesting - could the code above be running before the `is-expanded` class is added? That would explain why it works without `is-expanded` but doesn't with it

Comment: I think that is it! Was typing that probability when @Amit was responding. Glad we solved it! Now I need to find out how to listen for the clicks.

Comment: don't listen for clicks - see update to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your JS code is being executed before the `is-expanded` class is being set on the `a` element (probably body-onload).

Also, you could optimize your selector to:

```
jQuery("dt:has(a.is-expanded)")`
```

This means jQuery only returns a list with those `dt`'s that actually have the relevant children, which is a faster task than returning all `dt`'s (specially if there are many of them), and then filtering that list with another selection call.

Comment: Amit caught what was wrong! @CupawnTae should also get credit for extensive help.

Answer (score 1):

Qualify the `a` in the `.has()` with the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
jQuery("dt").has("a.selected").addClass("red");
```

Comment: That is what I initially tried, but without success. My dt is not updated with the new class when I write a.selected, only when I write a. But that is not what I want. This is my actual HTML, is-expanded is what I want to hit (I wrote selected above for simplicity): `<dt><a href="#accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger is-collapsed is-expanded" aria-expanded="true">Our services</a></dt>`

Comment: The class is still being added so perhaps there is something else that's interfering with it

Answer (score 1):

You can include the `selected` class in the `has()` selector.

To trigger the code whenever the accordion changes, listen for `create` and `activate` events on the accordion: https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#events

```js
jQuery("dt").has("a.is-expanded").addClass("is-expanded");
```

```css
.is-expanded {background:red}
.is-expanded a {color: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dt><a href="#accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger is-collapsed is-expanded" aria-expanded="true">Our services</a></dt>
<dt><a href="#accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger is-collapsed" aria-expanded="true">Other</a></dt>
```

Comment: That is what I initially tried, but without success. My dt is not updated with the new class when I write a.selected, only when I write a. But that is not what I want. This is my actual HTML, is-expanded is what I want to hit (I wrote selected above for simplicity): `<dt><a href="#accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger is-collapsed is-expanded" aria-expanded="true">Our services</a></dt>`

Comment: You should put your actual code, both HTML and JS in your question - as you can see if you run my snippet, it *does* work, so there must be something else having an effect.

Comment: I've updated my snippet with your actual HTML - note that setting the `color` on the `dt` won't change the colour of the link (so I've changed it to `background` for demonstration purposes) - could that be your issue?

Comment: @pastic Still works, even with your HTML and JS - have you checked in web inspector to make sure the class definitely isn't added? Could it be added but it's just not having the effect you're expecting?

Comment: I see your version is working and am really confused. I am checking with firebug. When I do a only the class is added and I get the expected CSS styling to appear. When I do a.is-expanded the class is not added and hence no styling appears.

Comment: I think I know why - is the problem that the script runs on page load when there is no is-expanded in the html? I perhaps need the jquery to run when I click the respective accordion header which is what puts the is-expanded on the a? Do I need to specify a click event of some sort?

Comment: Undoubtedly. You can listen for `create` and `activate` events on the accordion itself https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#events

Comment: (added to answer, although @Amit deserves credit for thinking of the timing issue first)